# How do I make an Image appear for a specified amount of time when a button is Clicked? In eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview, jodatime

Just wondering how I can make a button click make an image view appear for like half a sec then disappear, until the button is clicked again. I'm using joda-time

Here's what I have. I'm new to java if you couldn't already tell.

```
public void onClick(View v) {   
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    dur = 1;
    if (barrelblast != 0)
        sp.play(barrelblast, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);  
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibe.vibrate (90);  

    if (dur != 0)
       smoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       Duration.standardSeconds(1);
```

Comment: I think the most common way to do this would be to use a TimerTask: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: Have a look at Handler.postDelayed: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29

Comment: You want your image to show for half a second or to show until the button is clicked again?

Comment: I want it to show for half a sec then disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public void onClick(View v){

smoke.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Handler delayedAction = new Handler();

delayedAction.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

public void run() {

smoke.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }

       }, 500);

}
```

Comment: Well that worked like a charm. You sir is awesome. If you have any time to explain how that works I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: As for explaining... Well that's up to you, if you really want to program read the documentation, experiment and also, read again. :)